# typewriter font in times new roman

Tags: typewriter, times

Given,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
    This is textual typewriter {\tt Angry Hyena kills Lion to save her baby}
    
    This is mathematical typewriter ${\tt Angry~Hyena~kills~Lion~to~save~her~baby}$
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

one may notice that the styles for the typewriter fonts are quite different. What I am looking for is to change the textual style to the other. So, when I uses `{\tt ...}`, I get the style for `${\tt ...}$`.

Comment: don't use times (it is a very old package) use a more modern times clone with a matching font set eg `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` also don't use `\tt` it has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, use `\texttt{abc}` in text and `\mathtt{abc}` in math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restore the default computer modern tt font with `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}`.  Note also, `\texttt{}` is the preferred invocation syntax for LaTeX in text mode and `\mathtt{}` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{document}
    This is textual typewriter \texttt{Angry Hyena kills Lion to save her baby}
    
    This is mathematical typewriter $\mathtt{%
      Angry~Hyena~kills~Lion~to~save~her~baby}$
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The executable code of the [times](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/times) package consists of just a few lines:

```
\ProvidesPackage{times}%
[2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3
(SPQR)
]
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Helvetica clone
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % Times Roman clone
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr} % Courier clone
\endinput
```

If all you want to do is change the roman (serif) font to a Times Roman clone, you shouldn't execute `\usepackage{times}`. Instead, just execute

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

---

A small MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\newcommand\HW{Hello, World}
\begin{document}
\obeylines %just for this example
\HW. \textit{\HW}. 
\textbf{\HW}. \textbf{\textit{\HW}}. 
\textsc{\HW}. \textbf{\textsc{\HW}}.
\end{document}
```