# Change mathematical font in times new roman

Tags: math-mode, times

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605793/typewriter-font-in-times-new-roman), consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
    Textual numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    
    Numbers in mathematics mode: $0~1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I set the text mode numbers look similar to that of mathematical mode? In other words, I want to get `$2$` when I write `2`.

Comment: The `times` package has been obsolete for more than 25 years. Use `mathptmx` for a cheap hack or, better, `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Comment: as I commented on your previous question and @egreg commented just now on this, use `newtxtext,newtxmath`

Comment: @egreg Yeah, David Carlisle  mentioned that in the other question.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I suggest using the more recent packages, `newtxtext` and `\newtxmath`, to implement times roman in text and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
% xxx \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
    Textual numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    
    Numbers in mathematics mode: $0~1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you insist on using the `times` package, another alternative for times math would be the `mathptmx` package.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I wanted the other way around, get mathematical font all the time.

Comment: @hola There is always the option of using `text $1$ more text` in text mode, in order to achieve the math font for numerals.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question you literally asked, `unicode-math` allows you to load TeX Gyre Termes Math as your math font and, optionally, TImes New Roman for your letters and digits.  `mathspec` allows you to load Times New Roman as your font for letters and digits, with `newtxmath` for all other symbols.